# Github Actions badge shows "No status"

Tags: github, github-actions

got a trouble with GitHub Actions badges.

I have three [workflows](https://github.com/riZZZhik/belinsky/tree/master/.github/workflows) in my repository.

And I am trying to get their badges in [Readme](https://github.com/riZZZhik/belinsky/blob/master/README.md) using GitHub links:
https://github.com/riZZZhik/belinsky/actions/workflows/tests.yaml/badge.svg
https://github.com/riZZZhik/belinsky/actions/workflows/code_analyzis.yaml/badge.svg
https://github.com/riZZZhik/belinsky/actions/workflows/push_docker_image.yaml/badge.svg

Badges images have "no status" values: 
[image: Badges]) 
which is strange, because workflows correctly completed: https://github.com/riZZZhik/belinsky/actions

The question is how to make badges show "passed" / "not passed" based on workflow execution

Comment: Your badge seems to be referenced correctly. Probably has something to do with the degraded GitHub Actions performance today https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: @timmeinerzhagen Oh, if this is true then I just lost my last couple hours. 
Thanks, I'll wait then until GitHub fixes this.

Comment: I have the same problem.
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868471/github-ci-badge-shows-no-status)

Comment: Solution is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868471/github-ci-badge-shows-no-status/71876479#71876479](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868471/github-ci-badge-shows-no-status/71876479#71876479)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem.
Using the link below instead seems to work.

https://github.com/riZZZhik/belinsky/workflows/Unittests/badge.svg

Comment: Yeah, link to workflow name works rather then to workflow file, but in theory both of them should.

Comment: I have the same issue recently, and this is solved the problem. But I have old repos where using `.yml` is work instead of `.yaml`. Have a look at https://github.com/injustease/gostman/actions/workflows/ci.yml/badge.svg

Answer (score 1):

Also if you use workflow named with space as `Android CI` you have to put there url space character as

original problematic:

```
[![Android CI](https://github.com/renetik/renetik-android-core/actions/workflows/android.yml/badge.svg)](https://github.com/renetik/renetik-android-core/actions/workflows/android.yml)
```

new somehow not problematic:

```
[![Android CI](https://github.com/renetik/renetik-android-core/workflows/Android%20CI/badge.svg)](https://github.com/renetik/renetik-android-core/actions/workflows/android.yml)
```

Comment: This worked for me, seems to be an issue with needing a URL safe workflow name