# GitHub CI badge shows "no status"

Tags: github, workflow, status, badge

Create badge image:

[image: Create badge image]

Created badge image result:

[[image: Created badge image result]

Why is there not a "passing"/"failed"/"succeeded"?

[Workflows](https://github.com/sunnamed434/UIElementsUnturned/actions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've run into this before, try using the name of the Action instead of the workflow file name.

[image: CI]

This snippet should work for you:

```
[![CI](https://github.com/sunnamed434/UIElementsUnturned/workflows/CI/badge.svg
)](https://github.com/sunnamed434/UIElementsUnturned/actions/workflows/NET_Framework_CI.yml)
```

Comment: It seems like this is a new issue: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/14980

Answer (score 2):

the first URL shoul be without /actions
like this https://github.com/thereapr/reincarnated_mod/workflows/CI/badge.svg

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but neither the filename nor the workflow name works for me :(

```
[![CI](https://github.com/thereapr/reincarnated_mod/actions/workflows/gradle.yml/badge.svg)](https://github.com/thereapr/reincarnated_mod/actions/workflows/gradle.yml)

[![CI](https://github.com/thereapr/reincarnated_mod/actions/workflows/CI/badge.svg)](https://github.com/thereapr/reincarnated_mod/actions/workflows/gradle.yml)
```

Comment: This should work for you:  

https://github.com/thereapr/reincarnated_mod/workflows/CI/badge.svg

Have to remember to remove `actions` from the URL when using the workflow name.