# Github Actions badge shows no status

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions, badge

I have run many times github actions on my repo without problem and with the same script on one of my repo it is displaying “no status”.
The repo is: https://github.com/aurelpere/python-planif

I dont understand why it is not displaying a status as the workflow runs correctly…
Any help would be great
thank you

Notice my svg badge also shows "no status" at https://github.com/aurelpere/python-planif/workflows/CI/badge.svg and at https://github.com/aurelpere/python-planif/workflows/Unittests/badge.svg .
(following what is in this post : https://github.community/t/badge-shows-no-status-and-no-status-mismatch-between-the-filepath-vs-name-usage/16907 or in this post [Github Actions badge shows "No status"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71863833/github-actions-badge-shows-no-status))

I also tried to duplicate the code in another fresh repo (https://github.com/aurelpere/python-geothermal---power-to-gas/
) and it is the same, the badge shows no status, so it has nothing to do with the fast forward merge issue from here https://github.community/t/workflow-badge-no-status/17280/2

Edit : solved with the answer below, but i deleted the initial repo and kept only the fresh one if you try to follow the links

Comment: same here, do update us if you figure it out

Comment: i solved this problem, check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868471/github-ci-badge-shows-no-status)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub CI badge shows "no status"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868471/github-ci-badge-shows-no-status)

Comment: thanks, the solution below worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you have to use the workflow name instead of the yaml file name. This worked for me

```
<a href="https://github.com/pgonzaleznetwork/forcemula/actions/workflows/nodejs.yaml">
    <img src="https://github.com/pgonzaleznetwork/forcemula/workflows/Tests/badge.svg?style=flat" />
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Weird, tried it with the workflow name but mine goes directly to the workflow page, completely ignoring the "/badge.svn" part

Comment: But does it show the actual status? That was the main issue on this thread