# GitHub action status badge showing No Status

Tags: github-actions, workflow, badge

I'm attempting to add a badge to my GitHub repo showing the status of unit tests. I followed the guide, shown [here](https://dev.to/robdwaller/how-to-add-a-github-actions-badge-to-your-project-11ci), and produced the following change to my repo:

```
[![Unit Tests Status](https://github.com/xefino/goutils/workflows/Unit%20Tests/badge.svg)](https://github.com/xefino/goutils/actions)
```

However, when I navigate to the repo's page on GitHub, I see that the action shows "No Status". I understand, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896000/github-actions-badge-shows-no-status), that the name described in the workflow's YAML file has to match the URL, which mine does. So I'm having trouble understanding why I'm not seeing a status on the badge. Does anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue here. My URL was not actually correct, not because of some typo, but because the format had changed. So, doing this worked:

```
[![Unit Tests Status](https://github.com/xefino/goutils/actions/workflows/test.yml/badge.svg)](https://github.com/xefino/goutils/actions)
```